# Setting login path within ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC and Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.2

Project details:

- ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC
- Identity

I created an **own login view**. Actually if I call a view, for which I have to be authorized (by **authorize attribute**), it will automatically redirected to the login view. But at the moment it's "/Identity/Account/Login". But **I want, that my own login view is shown**. How can I do that?

I already tried this within startup.cs:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(config => { config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true; })
    .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options => { options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true; });
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = "auth_cookie";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/Login";
        options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
        options.LogoutPath = "/Account/LogOff";
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
        options.ReturnUrlParameter = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    });
```

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? Unsure what you mean by "your own view" wherein you could modify the current View (`cshtml`) as needed or the `Account` controller itself to return some view(?).

Comment: I do not want to use the login view within the identity nuget package which is called by /Identity/Account/Login. How can I modify the Account controller which is in the identity package? So I created an own account controller with login which is called by /Account/Login and not /Identity/Account/Login

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could try to configure `CookieAuthenticationOptions` to achieve your requirement.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
        .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

    services.PostConfigure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme,
    opt =>
    {
        //configure your other properties
        opt.LoginPath = "/Login";
    });
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
```

Comment: I have 2 section in my app 1. Admin 2.Client, Whenever client enters i want to redirect him to the "account/login" but for admins "admin/account/login" how to do this?a

Comment: PostConfigure is exactly what I was looking for to configure oAuth settings. For example if using Google and I need the scheme to go to a specific login page. Thanks!