# ASP.NET CORE MVC IDENTITY How to change url of defualt log in page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have authentification using Identity.
But if I use [Authorize] atribute, I`m redirected to
localhost:7174/Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FUser%2FUser while I don't have such page. How to change this url? I didn't find any methods or properties that can change that.
Also, I added that Identity pages with Scaffold. But even now it said that it's impossible to reach such page. What should I better do?

I don't know what could be usefull for you, so here is my program.cs

```
using DreamWeb.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;


var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddMvc();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(); 
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DreamsContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer("server = SCAT\\SQLEXPRESS; database = dreams_web; Trusted_Connection=True ; MultipleActiveResultSets = true"));
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<UserAccount>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DreamsContext>();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddCookie();


builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;

    options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 1;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
});

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

Comment: You can specify additional options for added service, login/logout path in that case: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookieauthenticationoptions?view=aspnetcore-6.0 . Same for older ones.

Comment: As for the 2nd question, You never add those added pages to the route. Upadte `MapControllerRoute` with additional entries. You can use `MapControllers` if you like to move from the table to attribute based routing.

Comment: Hello are you still having the issue? Did you tried the solution provided?

Answer (score 2):

If you look [here](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/options.html#refoptions) in the documentation there seems to be an option you can pass in on startup that allows you to set that url names "loginUrl"

> UserInteraction
> LoginUrl, LogoutUrl, ConsentUrl, ErrorUrl, DeviceVerificationUrl
> Sets the URLs for the login, logout, consent, error and device verification pages.

so reasonably you should be able to do

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(
      options =>
        {
            ...
            options.loginUrl = "myLoginUrl"
        }
    );
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

About changing default login path.
The best way I've found is changing it with CookieAuthenticationOptions in my program.cs:

```
builder.Services.PostConfigure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/SignIn";
});
```

Attempts to change it in other way (with identity server) had no success.

This helped me:[Setting login path within ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC and Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54959280/setting-login-path-within-asp-net-core-2-2-mvc-and-identity).

As for second question (about Identity scaffolded pages, that cant be reached), I was missing this in my program.cs:

```
app.MapRazorFiles();
```