# ASP.NET WebApi returns HTTP 404 instead of HTTP 401

Tags: authorization, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi, http-error

the simple scaffolded Individual Authentication from Program.cs, :

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

// ...
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
  name: "default",
  pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

the controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("/api/myresource")]
public class MyResourceController : ControllerBase {
// ...

    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet("dummy")]
    public IActionResult GetDummy()
    {
        return Ok(new Dummy());
    }
```

When I GET /api/myresource/dummy it returns HTTP 404 instead of HTTP 401.

Use cases:

- If I comment out the `[Authorize]` attribute: Works fine, returns with dummy data (so I suppose the routing is in place and working)
- If the `[Authorize]` attribute is in place and I logged in: Works fine, returns with dummy data (so I suppose the routing is in place and working)
- If the `[Authorize]` attribute is in place and I **not** logged in: returns HTTP 404 instead of HTTP 401, the method not even called.

**Question**

I would like the API return with HTTP 401. I suppose this should behave this way out of the box, so there is something I am doing wrong. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, I think it is caused by when you accessing an endpoint protected by `[Authroize]`, If you are not logged in, The project will redirect you to login endpoint, But when project don't find the login endpoint, It will show 404 error. You can follow this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54959280/setting-login-path-within-asp-net-core-2-2-mvc-and-identity) to configure your login endpoint or you can follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34880817/make-web-api-authentication-return-401-instead-of-redirect-to-login-page) to make project return 401 error directly instead of redirecting to login endpoint.

Comment: Hi @g.pickardou, Can this answer help you solve this issue?